# NativeScript advanced binding in xml

Tags: xml, listview, binding, nativescript, itemtemplate

I'm trying to archive a way to use binding from xml in a way to be able to:
swap textField hint via xml binding to get value from an array using dropdown selected index. For example: `$parents['listView'].unit[$parents['listView'].index_reference_types]`

where unit is an array which has unit text for hint.

```
<GridLayout row="0" rows="*,*">
    <dd:DropDown cssClass="dropDownGrid" id="dropDown" items="{{ $parents['listView'].types }}" selectedIndex="{{ $parents['listView'].types, index_types }}"/>
</GridLayout>
<GridLayout col="1" columns="*" rows="*">
    <TextField hint="{{ unit }}" minWidth="50" textAlignment="center" isEnabled="true" keyboardType="number" text="{{ $parents['listView'].hours, hours }}" />
</GridLayout>
```

What makes this harder is a listview itemTemplate full of individual dropDown lists, inputfields and so on.

How can I make inside listview template being views change like on dropDown selection to fire event  (this way I could refresh the listview to get correct values) or how can I set those {{ unit }}'s from array based on the selection of dropDown list. Well basically both are same where firing an event from drop down is better, but not working like outside listview ones are.

Comment: The 'question' is missing the QUESTION part.

Comment: Added the question part